# Como converter Enum para int preenchendo com zero a esquerda?

Tags: c#, string, conversão-de-tipo, enums

Caros colegas, estou com uma duvida aqui em converter um `enum` em uma `string`, mas preciso que na conversão seja preenchido com zero para manter 2 dígitos.

Exemplo

```
public enum System
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Mirror = 3,
    Order = 17
}
```

o enum Mirror o out put seria "03".

tentei com esse exemplo abaixo funcionou

```
        int value;
        value = 3;
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("D2"));
        // Displays 03
```

Mas com Enum nao funciona.

```
Console.WriteLine(SourceSystem.Mirror.ToString("D2"));
```

Aparece o Seguinte erro:

> ```
> System.FormatException 
> Message=Format String can be only "G", "g", "X", "x", "F", "f", "D" or "d".....
> ```

Segue o `enum`:

```
    public enum SourceSystem
  {
    Unknown = 0,
    Mirror = 3,
    MirrorTrident = 17
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro precisa pegar o valor com um *cast* por exemplo, e depois transformar em `string`, o padrão do `ToString()` do `enum` é dar a descrição do nome dele.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(((int)SourceSystem.Mirror).ToString("D2"));
    }
}

public enum SourceSystem {
    Unknown = 0,
    Mirror = 3,
    MirrorTrident = 17
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Uh7ocv). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MhoywJ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enum/ValueToString.cs).